# Why I can't see my web app home page when uploading online?

Tags: node.js

I have build a NodeJS app with the entry file `index.js` that serve all my static files (css, file, views). When I uploaded my app to be online I couldn't see my home page, instead the host website or server showed a message saying: `you are seeing this page because you don't have index.html or index.php file in your public folder` I have index.js

```html
<!--pixels game
     > controllers
     > css
     > img
     > js
     > views 
       index.js
       package-lock.json
       storage.json
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index.html that includes your index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i did that an error occurs saying"require function is not defined" i think the server try to read it as plain javascript code not node.js code

Comment: Can you share your index.js file

Comment: i have used 'heroku.com' site and deployed my app , all good brother .